# Set alignment and padding of first and second column in <table> via CSS

Tags: html, css

How can I align the first column to the right and second column to the left and padded 10px with CSS?

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td align="right">Skype:</td><td align="left"> sent</td></tr>
        <tr><td align="right">Tel:</td><td align="left"> +343 343 4343</td></tr>
        <tr><td align="right">e-mail:</td><td align="left"> info@example.com</td></tr>
        <tr><td></td><td align="left"> example@gmail.com</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use the `:first-child` selector, like this:

```
td { padding: 10px }
td:first-child { text-align: right }
```

No aligning is needed in your table anymore.

Answer (score 6):

While this is the easiest, it doesn't work in all browsers (specifically older versions):

```
/* While :first-child or :first-of-type (equivalent to this) could have been
 * used, :nth-of-type(n) is easier to change if you ever decide you want
 * different columns to be aligned */
tr td:nth-of-type(1) {
 text-align:right;
}
tr td:nth-of-type(2) {
 text-align:left;
 padding-left:10px;
}
```

However, by replacing `:nth-of-type(1)` with `.first` and `:nth-of-type(2)` with `.second`, and adding `class="first"` and `class="second"` to the first and second `<td>` in each row, respectively, you'll get better browser support.

If you're looking to add padding to all cells, simply add:

```
td {
 padding:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS

```
table td {
     padding: 10px;
}
.alignright {
     text-align: right;
}
```

HTML

```
<table>
     <tbody>
          <tr>
               <td>Skype:</td>
               <td>sent</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
               <td>Tel:</td>
               <td class="alignright">+343 343 4343</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
               <td>e-mail:</td>
               <td class="alignright">info@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
               <td colspan="2">example@gmail.com</td>
          </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

you mean with an external stylesheet? like this:

#### HTML

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td class="right">Skype:</td><td class="left"> sent</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="right">Tel:</td><td class="left"> +343 343 4343</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="right">e-mail:</td><td class="left"> info@example.com</td></tr>
        <tr><td></td><td class="left"> example@gmail.com</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

#### CSS

```
td {
    padding: 10px;
}
td.right {
    align: right;
}
td.left {
    align: left;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's true way, but not perfect one

Answer (score 0):

I usually style this info in this manner:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td class="left">Skype:</td><td class="right"> sent</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="left">Tel:</td><td class="right"> +343 343 4343</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="left">e-mail:</td><td class="right"> info@example.com</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="left"> </td><td class="right padding"> example@gmail.com</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>



.left {float:left; padding-right:10px; width:50px; text-align:right;}

.right {float:left}

.padding {padding-left:60px;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/R9YPF/