# How to add column padding to the first column of a specific table in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a table which is created dynamically in javascript.

EDIT: Example code to create the table is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/evo5dh2u/):

I need to add spacing between the two columns (e.g. 50px). I have read that the best way is to add padding to the right of the first column, but I am not sure how to add the spacing to the first column in javascript using the table's class name?

I added the CSS provided in the original answers like so:

`.informationWindowTable > tr > td:first-child {padding-right:50px;}`

but it does not get applied to the table and that is why I asked for a solution in javascript. How do I ensure that the CSS is called only after the table is created?

Comment: Why javascript ? CSS is what should be used for styling and since you already have a class on the table you should use that.

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli, I edited the question to make it clear why I asked for Javascript, but if there is an answer for CSS it would also help.

Answer (score 5):

This is best done in CSS

```
table tr td:first-child {
  padding-right: 50px;
}
```

However, it can be done in JavaScript

```
var tableCells = document.querySelectorAll("table tr td:first-child");

for (var i = 0; i < tableCells.length; i++) {
    tableCells[i].classList.add("give-padding");
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8y9qc0o0/

Instead of adding to the `classList`, you can also use the `document.style.property` syntax.

```
tableCells[i].style.padding-right("50px");
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the usecase [border-spacing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/border-spacing) property might also be useful:

```css
.tab {
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 50px 1px;
}
.tab td {border: 1px #AAA solid; padding: 10px;}
```

```html
<table class="tab">
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should CSS to accomplish that. Use the :first-child selector.

```
td:first-child { text-align: right }
```

Font: [Set alignment and padding of first and second column in <table> via CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10058189/set-alignment-and-padding-of-first-and-second-column-in-table-via-css)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps splitting the padding between the two `td` is the best for balance

```css
.tab td:nth-child(even) {padding-left:25px;}
.tab td:nth-child(odd){padding-right:25px;}
```

```html
<table class="tab">
    <tr>
       <td>1</td>
       <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>3</td>
       <td>4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```